# Confusion on how to create CrossTab in Python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to create a cross tab on python using this code

```
cross_tab= pd.crosstab(All_Durham_Crime_Dec20_to_Feb21['Crime type'],All_Durham_Crime_Dec20_to_Feb21['Month'])
```

It says

> 'method' object is not subscriptable

I was wondering if anyone knew where I was going wrong.

Comment: This error means, that you're trying to get an element from a non-indexed data structure. Please verify if `All_Durham_Crime_Dec20_to_Feb21` is a DataFrame. Most probably you might have a function with the same name. Without seeing the full code, can't help further.

Comment: What have you set `All_Durham_Crime_Dec20_to_Feb21` to? Add the line which has `All_Durham_Crime_Dec20_to_Feb21 = ...`.